# How can I return a bool from objc(Xcode) to Unity OR execute a function in xCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am quite in Unity but I face a problem that I couldn't solve after days of research. I simply want to execute a function on my iPhone when the camera permission for the App I created is not given by the user. I want to show an alert message like in the code below(which works when I put the whole alertView-stuff inside the if-statement). But I cannot figure out how to place this IBAction there (so that the button also works). It would ofc be better if xCode would return a variable like an int or a boolean to Unity and I could execute some functions in there to advice the user.

Basically the flow is the following:

1. User wants to make a pic
2. UIAlert pops up "You need to give camera permission blabla"
3. User chooses "go to settings" and it opens the settings.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
#include "PermissionCamPlugin.h"
#import "PermissionCamPlugin.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <Foundation/NSException.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@implementation alertViewController

-(IBAction)alertbutton
{
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"oops... "
                                                message:@"If you want to enable the camera go to the settings."
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"close"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"go to settings", nil];
[alert show];
}
  -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == 1)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}
}
@end

  BOOL CameraCheckDone = NO;
  BOOL CamPermGiven = NO;

 void sd_camera_permission()
 {

if ([AVCaptureDevice respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessForMediaType:completionHandler:)]) {
    // Completion handler will be dispatched on a separate thread
    [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (YES == granted)
        {
            CamPermGiven = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            CamPermGiven = NO;

            //HERE I WANT TO EXECUTE THE ALERT CALL AND ALSO EXECUTE THE BUTTON FUNCTION IF THE USER CHOOSES SO
        }

        // (no matter if the 'granted' is YES or NO)
        CameraCheckDone = YES;
    }];
}
else {
    // iOS < 7 (camera access always OK)

    CameraCheckDone = YES;
    // Continue with app launch...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function in this class and call this function from Unity when the app is launched or you can also write Unity Send Message in  .m file to call unity function.

Xcode .m file:

extern "C"
{

```
bool getCameraStatus()
{

    return CamPermGiven;

}
```

}

Unity class:
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
 private static extern bool getCameraStatus ();

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem. Have a nice day

Comment: My Pleasure. Kudos